# Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object 'netlfix' not found

Tags: r

Im trying to plot of the adjusted price of the netflix stock. I used this code

```
netflix<- tq_get("NFLX", 
              from = '2009-01-01',
              to = '2018-03-01',
              get  = 'stock prices'
              )


netlfix %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=date, y=adjusted)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle ("Netflix since 2009") +
  labs(x="date","Price") +
  scale_x_date(date_breks = "years", date_labels = "%Y")
  theme_bw
```

And I get that error message.

Comment: You misspelled `netflix` as `netlfix`. That leads to an error where the object is not found. (Usually, this error message means that you misspelled something or have forgotten to create an object)

Comment: Thank you Martin! i changed it and it worked